# How to change text of a TextView from OnListItemClick in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

:)

I am trying to create an application that shows a ListFragment.
When one of the items in the ListFragment is clicked by the user
it changes the text in the TextView of an another activity.

I have tried this approach so far:

(This is in the Fragment activity, item is a static string)

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    item = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

  Intent intent = new Intent(AboutFragment.this.getActivity(),Shower.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

(This is in the empty activity that takes the item's string and uses it to determine what to show on the TextView)

```
TextView texter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shower);

    texter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    Setter();

    }


public void Setter(){
    switch (AboutFragment.item.toString()) {

        case "moon": texter.setText("Mortal");
        case "blue":texter.setText("Job");

    }
}
```

Currently it only shows the word "Job", it doesnt change when I click the other word. I tried using the onResume, but to no avail.

Thanks for any help provided. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a break statement to terminate the execution of the switch.  Without it, the "moon" case executes, immediately followed by execution of the "job" case which results in the behavior you describe.

```
switch (AboutFragment.item.toString()) {

    case "moon": texter.setText("Mortal");
          break;// add this or else the next case will execute
    case "blue":texter.setText("Job");
          break;// you should add this too

}
```

Comment: I can't believe I fell for such a dumb mistake... The application is working fine now, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use `putExtras()`? Maybe it will do what you want easily.

### Example

1- First of all the `onListItemClick()` should be like :

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 String text = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Shower.class);
 intent.putExtra("KeyString", text);
 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

2- In your`empty Activity` you should do this :

```
TextView texter;
String myText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_shower);
 texter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
 if (extras != null) {
    myText = extras.getString("KeyString");
 }
  Setter();
}


public void Setter(){
 switch (myText) {
     case "moon": texter.setText("Mortal");
      break;
     case "blue":texter.setText("Job");
      break;
}
```

}

Hope it helps... I tried to understan your problem so let me know if it's what you want.

Comment: I've solved my problem but thanks for giving me this method, I was trying to do it with intent(Extra_Message, item) but it wasnt for fragment. Much appreciated :)